# Why this pointer captured by lambda is corrupted while other variable is not

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, lambda

I have compiled (g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp) and run following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class A {
    std::function<void(void)> f;
public:
    A(std::function<void(void)> pf) : f(pf) {}
    void callf() { f(); }
};

class B {
    A *a;
public:
    void test() {
        B *that = this;
        auto f = [this, that]() {
            cout << "this: " << this << " that: " << that << endl;
            delete this->a;
            cout << "this: " << this << " that: " << that << endl;
        };

        a = new A(f);
        a->callf();
    }
};

int main()
{
    B().test();
}
```

Its output was:

```
this: 0x7fff158c88f0 that: 0x7fff158c88f0
this: 0x1ea3000 that: 0x7fff158c88f0
```

I do not understand why captured this changed its value while identical pointer with different name was not corrupted.

**Edit:**

I understand that lambda is destroyed and I am producing UB but what I do not understand is why one variable is corrupted while other not. I do not understand low level details behind this behaviour which is by the way very consistent. I want to understand gcc implementation details that cause this kind of behaviour.

My further investigation showed that changing `auto f = [this, that]` to `auto f = [that, this]` caused that to be corrupted.

Answer (score 6):

Undefined behaviour, innit. You just destroyed the lambda you're executing.

Comment: I undetstand I destroyed class which holds captured variables (this is lamda) but why it is consistent behaviour that this is corrupted while that not.

Comment: @Trismegistos, Undefined behaviour can be consistent. Or it can be inconsistent.

Comment: Who knows? Maybe `~function()` does something to the memory it formerly occupied. Or maybe something inside that `cout` chain is reappropriating the memory formerly occupied by `*a` and storing new data there.

Comment: I edited question (added last paragraph) where I explain that I understand it is UB. What I do not understand is low level technical reason.

Comment: @Trismegistos In addition, undefined behaviour does not always have a simple "low-level" reason like certain bytes of memory being overwritten. In some cases it can also be because the compiler may produce code that only tries to do the right thing only under the assumption that UB does not occur.

Comment: @Trismegistos There is certain undefined behavior that you can make sense of and sometimes cautiously take behavioral dependencies on, for example reinterpreting a `float*` as an `unisnged int*` to extract the exponent field.  This case is not one of them.

Comment: @MooseBoys: Don't do that. UB might easily get you later.

Comment: Destroying an object while one of its member functions is running does not invoke undefined behavior. Referencing the object after it is destroyed does.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `delete this->a;` and `this->a` is what holds `f`, leading to UB.

Comment: I know but why one variable is corrupted while other not.

Comment: Chasing UB, especially when it deals with contents of freed memory locations isn't very meaningful. This behaviour will not be portable and will depend on various factors. It might not even be perfectly reproducible on your machine.

Comment: Even "on your machine" is far too general: On your exact implementations (which includes the specific compiler-options used).